# Intei i7 vs i5 using java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am developing a web based application.

The computer where I write the code has 4 core **Intel i5 4440** 3.10 GHz processor.

The computer where I deploy the application has 8 core **Intel i7 4790K** 4.00 GHz processor.

One of the tasks that needs to be calculated is very heavy so I decided to use the java executor framework.

I have this:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
```

and then I add 30 tasks at once.

On my development machine the result was calculated in **3 seconds** (it used to be **20 secs.** when I used only one thread) whereas on the server machine it got calculated in **16 seconds** ( which is the same as it used to be when the code used only one thread ).

As you can guess I am quite confused and have no idea why on the server machine it got calculated so much slower.

Anyone who knows why the faster processor does not get benefits from the multithreading algorithm?

Comment: Is it possible that you executed the old .class file (single threaded) in your development machine? Also, did you try multiple executions just to check if the CPU was busy with something else?

Comment: No i havent uploaded the old .class file. I tried more than enought executions. I am very confused

Comment: Do the threads access any shared data structure? If that's the case, there could be more contention.

Comment: Nope, they dont access any shared data

Comment: Can you disclose some information about the kind of operations that are being done? There would be little or no explanation if the tasks are CPU bound, so I'm suspecting the tasks you're trying to do might be IO bound.

Comment: Neither of these processors is for servers. Core processor line is for clients. Xeon processors are for servers.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to guess root cause without more evidence. Could you

- profile running application on server machine?
- connect to server machine with [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) and see threading info

My guess is that server machine is under heavy load (maybe from other applications or background threads?). Maybe your server user/java application is allowed to use only core?

I would start with using *top* (on linux) or Task Manager (windows) to find out if server is under load when you run your application. Profiling/JMX monitoring adds overhead, but you will be able to find out how many threads are actually used.

Final note- is server using same architecture (32/64bit), operating system and major/minor Java version than development?

Comment: Do u want to get team viewer access?